# groovy embed builder as script base class?

Tags: groovy

I want to embed a groovy script that invokes a builder.

So, I have this:

```
def cfg = new CompilerConfiguration()

cfg.setScriptBaseClass("SpoofBuilder")

def sh = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding(), cfg)

sh.evaluate(new File("test.builder"))
```

Where SpoofBuilder is copied from:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/BuilderSupport

test.builder contains

```
a {
    b { }
}
```

The result is that createNode is passed method main:

cn2
main
[]
nc
null
x

How can I cause "a" to be invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks no answer giving lovely down voter for contributing nothing but hatred to the world.

So, I have a lame solution. GroovyShell eventually uses InvokerHelper.createScript which invokes main if the parsed class does not derive from Script. So, essentially, I can evaluate a script and have it invoke the builder. But, I've only figured out how to get this to work by pasting text together and evaluating it. The pasted together text looks like:

```
class PoorSolution extends Script {
  def run() {
    new BadBuilder().a {
      b { }
    }
  }
}

class BadBuilder extends BuilderSupport {
  protected Object createNode(String name) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I would prefer to use GroovyScriptEngine so that the script will be reloaded when it's changed. But, that isn't going to work with a script that is pasted together and not in a file.